# Firebase & Postman | Generate JWT for Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, jwt, postman

I am trying to execute some administrative tasks on my Cloud Firestore (upload some data, ... etc.). I read through the documentations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)

> Use a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token and a service account to authenticate requests from your application, such as requests for database administration.

This referred to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) on how to make Authorized API Call after generating JWT. I am struggling with generating the JWT.

This is what I tried:

1. I formed the header and the claim set

   ```
   {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
   {
   "iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
   "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
   "aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
   "exp":1328554385,
   "iat":1328550785
   }
   ```
2. Went to https://jwt.io/ to generate JWT with RSA256. It asks for public key and private key. I understand the private key can be generated in json formate from service account I created under `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts`. However, I am not sure where to obtain the public key. jwt.io does not generate jwt. I only get 'invalid signature'.

There are many examples in the web using SDK or libraries. However, I could not see any example on how to generate JWT manually (if that is possible at all) to use it with Postman. Any idea?

Comment: I wrote an article that shows how to create a JWT, Sign it and then exchange for an Access Token. This will also explain the steps required. You can easily get the public key from the private key using openssl `openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem`. However, the public key is used by Google to verify your private key signing and you do not need it. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/ Here is a shortcut to creating an Access Token: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks a lot. This nudged me to the right direction. I managed to generate access token now. I will write the steps in the answer for future reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman - JWT authentication using key file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263373/postman-jwt-authentication-using-key-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnHanley. I managed to generate the token. This is not entirely withing Postman (I am still relying on jwt.io to generate the jwt).

1. after creating service account [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts). add a key and download the p12 file (not json). The default secret is `notasecret`
2. convert p12 to pem and extract the public key:
   `$openssl pkcs12 -in postman-admin-private.p12 -out postman-admin-private.pem -nodes`
   `$openssl rsa -in postman-admin-private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out postman-admin-public.pem`
3. Open both pem files and copy the private and public keys into jwt.io (using RSA256 option)
4. Make sure you use the email address of the service account in `iss` field
5. Here is the request in postman:

   `curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion='{generated jwt}'`

next would be to make it entirely within Postman. I have not tried that but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302263/generating-rsa-jwt-in-postman-pre-request-script) seems to be an option